# CABasicAnimation: What if CAShapeLayer position not changed?

Tags: ios, cabasicanimation, cashapelayer

I'm really new on the **CABasicAnimation** topic. If you want to animate the **x 
position** of an **CAShapeLayer** from the current x position to a specific x position you should
use the following:

```
    NSLog(@"CABasicAnimation now...");
    CABasicAnimation *layerPositionAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    [layerPositionAnimation setDuration:0.330];
    [layerPositionAnimation setRemovedOnCompletion: NO];
    [layerPositionAnimation setFillMode: kCAFillModeForwards];
    [layerPositionAnimation setTimingFunction: [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut]];
    [layerPositionAnimation setFromValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(self.shapeLayer.position.x, self.shapeLayer.position.y)]];
    [layerPositionAnimation setToValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(14.0, self.shapeLayer.position.y)]];
    [self.shapeLayer addAnimation:layerPositionAnimation forKey:@"layerPositionAnimation"];
```

In my case the self.shapeLayer is a CAShapeLayer used as a simple mask:

```
    [[overlayTopShadow layer] setMask:self.shapeLayer];
```

But what if the animation never happens (x position not changed)? What i'm doing wrong in my code? 
Any suggestions, ideas, examples?

Thanks a lot

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284343/cabasicanimation-not-animating-my-property

Comment: Thanks @MarkM I found that question before without a solution. Can you give a bit more support. The "position" as keyPath is correct, right?

Comment: I tried to animate the layer of the UIImageView [overlayTopShadow layer] and it works. But why i can't animate the shapelayer which i use as mask? I pretty sure I can but what I missed?

Comment: Note: If your view hosts custom layer objects—that is, layer objects without an associated view—you must use Core Animation to animate any changes to them. That may be the issue you are dealing with. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH6-SW2